# Why my Webform special token values not rendered correctly in D6?

Tags: 6, webforms, tokens

I am trying to use "*Special Tokens*" in the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module (6.x-3.18) on Drupal 6.  I'd like the data to populate a hidden field I've created with the email field on the same form.

Under default value for the hidden field I've tried using a number of different values including:

```
%post[submitted][email]<br />
%post[email]<br />
%post[submitted[email]]
```

None of this works.  If I go edit the email field, it tells me my key is `email`.  If I look at the name of the email field in the source code it's `submitted[email]`.

If anyone has any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this, I finally found a thread confirming that Webform tokens in D6 do not support arrays, and I had to apply a patch for the functionality to work.

This is **NOT** a problem in D7

http://drupal.org/node/824606

Patch - http://drupal.org/files/nested_tokens-824606-13.patch